# getData of "x" is not function when I set x to request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code:

```
    app.get('/',(req,res) => {
        var x = new Data();
        x.setData("Hello");
        console.log(x.getData()); // Hello
        req.x = x;
        x = req.x;
        console.log(x.getData()); // getData() is not a function ?? 
    });
```

please help me!!

Comment: `req.x` is not the same as `new Data()`

Comment: @david But, `x = new Data()` and `req.x = x`?

Comment: ah, i overlook that

Comment: you can add some debug info before and after `req.x = x;` by `console.log(req.x)`, I think req should be read-only, so you can't add additional fields to it. maybe you can try to add it to res.

Comment: @Spark.Bao If it were read-only, the error would be something like `x is undefined`

Comment: If you want to use `req`, let another variable and push into that. But why are you modifying req ?

Comment: `Data` is not a node.js class or a vanilla JavaScript class. You should also specify what `app` is, a vanilla `http.Server`, or Express.js app, or what? Please tag appropriately (and if possible include all relevant requires so we can experiment ourselves).

Comment: how can i save object `x`

Comment: I did an experiment and it works totally fine here, can you paste all your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my experiment code:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

class Data {
    constructor() {
        this.data = ''
    }

    setData(val) {
        this.data = val
    }

    getData() {
        return this.data
    }
}

// app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
        var x = new Data();
        x.setData("Hello");
        console.log(x.getData()); // Hello
        console.log(req.x)
        req.x = x;
        console.log(req.x)
        x = req.x;
        console.log(x)
        console.log(x.getData()); 
        res.send('Hello World!')
    });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

and this is the output:

```
> node app.js
Example app listening on port 3000!
Hello
undefined
Data { data: 'Hello' }
Data { data: 'Hello' }
Hello
```

has no error happened.